# Showing that $\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty(2j+1)e^{-j(j+1)x}=\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

In finding the [rotational partition function for a $C_{\infty v}$ molecule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_partition_function#Linear_molecules), one comes across the function
\begin{equation}
Z(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(2j+1)e^{-j(j+1)x}
\end{equation}
Surprisingly, this admits the Laurent series
\begin{equation}
Z(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{15}x+\frac{4}{315}x^2+\frac{1}{315}x^3+\ldots
\end{equation}
The first term is generally found as the approximation
\begin{equation}
Z(x)\approx \int_0^\infty(2j+1)e^{-j(j+1)x}dj=\frac{1}{x}\quad\quad\quad\text{for }x\ll1,
\end{equation}
and the rest of the terms can be found by the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). However, the Euler Maclaurin formula is a bit complicated, and I haven't figured out how to use it correctly to find the expansion of $Z(x)$. I am interested primarily in proving the value of the constant term
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(Z(x)-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{3}.
\end{equation}
I've tried expanding the exponentials as a Taylor series, but the constant terms end up adding to infinity, and I can't figure out how to annihilate them with an expansion of $\frac{1}{x}.$ Considering the $\frac{1}{x}$ term in the Laurent series for $Z(x)$, I figure that this problem might be able to be solved with Pade approximants, or Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: A rough argument is as follows. You can write the limit as $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 + } \frac{1}{{2i}}\int_\mathscr{C} {\cot (\pi t)(2t + 1)e^{ - t(t + 1)x} dt}  = \frac{1}{{2i}}\int_\mathscr{C} {\cot (\pi t)(2t + 1)dt} ,$$
where $\mathscr C$ is large positively oriented rectangular contour with vertices $\pm iT$ and $+\infty \pm iT$ with a small half-loop to avoide $t=0$. Manipulating the integral and then pushing $T\to \infty$ and collapsing the small loop into $0$ should give you $$
\frac{1}{2} - 4\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{t}{{e^{2\pi t}  - 1}}dt = \frac{1}{3}} .
$$

Comment: The accepted answer at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13779/how-to-make-approximation-of-rotational-partition-function-of-diatomic-linear-mo is very good

Comment: @Gary I see that that $$Z(x)=\frac{1}{2i}\oint_H \cot(\pi z)(2z+1)e^{-z(z+1)x}dz,$$ where $H$ is the Hankel contour, but I don't see how the $\frac{1}{x}$ term is factored in.

Comment: @Jacob I was not fully precise indeed. So if $f(t) = (2t + 1)e^{ - t(t + 1)x}$ and $\mathscr C_1$ and $\mathscr C_2$ are the upper and lower parts of $\mathscr C$, then $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 + } \left( Z(x) - \frac{1}{x} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 + } \left( \frac{1}{2i}\int_{\mathscr C} \cot (\pi t)f(t)dt  + \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathscr C_1 } f(t)dt  - \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathscr C_2 } f(t)dt  \right) \\ = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 + } \left( \int_{\mathscr C_1 } \frac{f(t)}{1-e^{ - 2\pi it} }dt  - \int_{\mathscr C_2 } \frac{f(t)}{1-e^{2\pi it} }dt \right).
$$